# Connecting android to a local server using XAMPP

Tags: php, android, xampp

I'm trying to fetch data from my local server to an android device, I was using a free online hosting service where everything worked fine before I encountered some non-related technical issues, so it's not likely the problem lies in the code itself(just a thought). Anyway, when I migrated to a local server using XAMPP, I get no response on my app of what so ever, I accessed the  php file from the mobile's browser and it's giving the right results, but the app itself gives complete silence. Searching through SO, most questions mentioned putting the right IP address in the file's URL. I'm using volley and I've inserted the very  same URL with with I accessed the file in the browser, the server doesn't seem to respond at all.

Here's the php code I'm using:

```
<?php
  include 'dbConnect.php';
$searchTerm='d';
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT term,id FROM tag WHERE term LIKE :searchTerm');
$query->execute(array(':searchTerm'=>$searchTerm.'%'));
$result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
?>
```

I'm using Volley library to contact the server, the first file is 
**CustomeAutoCompleteTextViewTextChangedListener.java**

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try {
            NetworkRequsts networkRequsts = new NetworkRequsts(context);
            networkRequsts.tagsJsonObjectRequest("https://192.168.110.1:8080/Register.php");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is where the request should be issued, notice the URL, this is where I think the problem is since it's the only thing I've changed in the code when I changed the server.

Here's the Volley request:

**NetworkRequsts.java**

```
JsonObjectRequest tagJsonRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(url,tagSearchObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    Log.d("Search term object",tagSearchObject.toString());
                    Log.d("respone Test", response.length()+" "+response.toString());
                    JASONArrayResponse=response.getJSONArray("result");
                    for(int i=0;i<JASONArrayResponse.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=JASONArrayResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("Volley", jsonObject.getString("term"));
                        Log.d("searchTerm",register.tagsAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());

                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException JE)
                {
                    JE.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: For successful running app through XAMPP you need to keep IP address same as you are systems IPs address where your server is running and both the system and your mobile device should be connected to same network. So cross check this points. You might be missing something here.

Comment: using `https` and port `8080` might cause a problem.

Comment: `the server doesn't seem to respond at all.` What do you mean? In onResponse() and onErrorResponse() you should place more Log statements. You are not covering the catch and all possibilities.

Comment: The app is not invoking any exceptions, the log.d should display the fetched JSON array from the server, but the log is not showing anything, just the character I type, and that's it

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the server is working perfectly, load in the browser using localhost and if works without fail, then change the ip address to the system ip. Then check your network connection properties where sharing is limited. Most of the cases the connection failure occurs because of the sharing limited by the Anti Virus program or something like that. After giving all the permissions it will work

Comment: I can access the file just fine from my PC(server) browser and the phone's browser, if it was an AV problem then why it's allowing the phone's browser to connect but not the app?

Comment: You haven't set any required permissions.

Comment: Probably you're missing android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: if this was the case it would have given an error, the permission is included

Comment: Did you add the jsonObjectRequest to requestQueue?